# Download pdf files using wget

Tags: wget, download

I tried use wget typing this command

```
wget -P  -e robots=off -A.pdf -r -l1 http://concours-maths-cpge.fr/
```

but I didn't succeed. I don't know the reason but perhaps because we need to click buttons to download files directly from the site. So what I can do?

Answer (score 5):

From the wget manual at GNU (https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html):

Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix. In this case, you have to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from expanding it, like in ‘-A "*.mp3"’ or ‘-A '*.mp3'’.

So you may try:

```
wget -P  -e robots=off -A pdf -r -l1 http://concours-maths-cpge.fr/
```